# ios seperatorView in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have added a seperator between cells to add spacing [cell with separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Suf.png)

But when I change color of seperatorView to `clearColor` from `blueColor` it disappears,can someone help ?

[image: seperator with clear color]

Here's my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let additionalSeperatorThickness = CGFloat(6)
    let additionalSeperator = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,
        cell.frame.size.height - additionalSeperatorThickness,
        cell.frame.size.width,
        additionalSeperatorThickness))
    additionalSeperator.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.addSubview(additionalSeperator)

   let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "text_box_1_converted.png")!)
    cell.backgroundView = imageView
    cell.bringSubviewToFront(additionalSeperator)

    return cell

}
```

Comment: its better make your own view in tableviewcell

Comment: As Muhammad suggested I would add a containing view to the cell and then add the image to it.

Comment: Consider what you are doing here.  Every time the cell gets dequed you are adding a subview and you never remove them.  Since the cell is reused every time it scrolls off screen you keep adding extra subviews.  This is why you should make your own class instead of manipulating the view hierarchy of UITableViewCell when you don't keep any references to the subviews.